# changing a sentence from "It is verb-ed that" to "subject is verb-ed to infinitive"

Tags: sentence-construction

The Cambridge book let me know following transition of sentence valid except for the verb : 'remember','suggest','decide',etc.

> It is said that he was the manager of the company.
>
> He is said to have been the manager of the company.

So the question is, how can I apply this in similar way to the verb 'remember' that bringing the subject of 'that' clause to the front, in the following sentence.

> It is strongly recommended that the machine should be fixed.

Would it be going like this?

> the machine is strongly recommended being fixed.??

or is it impossible?

Comment: After some verbs you can use different types of to+infinitive. **to have been** is perfect and **to be** is not! After ***suggest*** and some other verbs you cannot immediately use to+infinitive.

Comment: Your first "strongly" example displays 'extraposition'.The basic version would be the unsatisfactory "That the machine should be fixed is strongly recommended".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to understand the idea behind the verb.

The primary meaning of transitive **to recommend** means "to offer specific advice".

Of course, a typical flat tire or a broken machine cannot itself recommend that it be fixed. A **sentient** being (a person, or a device capable of sensing and communicating) recommends.

A photocopier with a computer diagnostic device inside it might recommend that you have the photocopier serviced.  But the photocopier itself is not making that recommendation.

That is why "the machine" cannot be moved to the subject position of a sentence where the verb is transitive **recommend**.

If the sentient being making the recommendation is not important at the moment, and the primary thought is that it would be advisable to do something, we can use so-called "dummy 'It'":

> It is recommended that you replace the car's  left headlight. It has
>   burned out.

There, "that you replace the car's  left headlight" fills the slot that "it" occupies.

Secondly, **to recommend** is not to declare a fact as we do when we say "He was manager of the company" or "That plant is poisonous to humans". Offering advice is not a statement of fact. So you will sometimes see the subjunctive used:

> It is recommended that the car's left headlight **be** fixed.

Comment: Just a reality check. Do you think *The machine is recommended to be fixed* is incorrect?

Comment: I think it is a locution that few native speakers alive today would use.

Comment: Though just the other day, in a comment to CowperKettle, I suggested "The drug is thought to act by ....." But what will fly with one verb won't fly with another.  We just wouldn't state the recommendation in the passive nowadays (to be fixed).  It is recommended *that*...

Comment: @TRomano then do you think it is wrong to say that "the machine is decided to be moved out"? I understood 'to recommend' is awkward to use like that but not for the verb 'decide' in somecases.

Comment: @JBL: Try to recast that statement in the active voice. It cannot be done, because the complement of **decide** cannot be "the machine to be moved out". Ungrammatical: *They decided the machine to be moved out.* We do hear this: *They recommended (that) the machine be moved out.* But we don't hear this: "They decided (that) the machine be moved out" (though it strikes my ear as marginal, not entirely impossible). Rather we hear: "They decided to move the machine out."

Comment: Or *They decided that the machine [should, would, must, could, might, ought to] be moved out.*